# How to properly wrap constructors with decorators in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

The process of wrapping a class with a decorator causes superclasses to be unable to access that classes' properties. Why?

I have some code that:

1. Creates a decorator which replaces the constructor of a class with a new constructor that should do the exact same thing.
2. Creates a base class with a property.
3. Wraps the base class with the wrapping decorator.
4. Creates a class that extends the base class.
5. Tries to access the property on the extended class. This is the part that fails.

Here is the code:

```
function wrap(target: any) {
  // the new constructor
  var f: any = function (...args) {
      return new target();
  }

  f.prototype = target.prototype;
  return f;
}

@wrap
class Base {
    prop: number = 5;
}

class Extended extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}

var a = new Extended()
console.log(new Extended().prop) // I'm expecting 5 here, but I get undefined.
```

I'm sure this is some nuance of either prototypes in general or the specific way that TypeScript handles them that I do not grasp.

Comment: I learned about methods and property decorators from this article: http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-ii

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This code [works](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-neumann-ikf3c?file=/src/index.ts) for me:

```
function logClass(target: any) {
  // save a reference to the original constructor
  var original = target;

  // the new constructor behaviour
  var f : any = function (...args) {
    console.log("New: " + original.name); 
    //return  original.apply(this, args);
    return new original(...args); // according the comments
  }

  // copy prototype so intanceof operator still works
  f.prototype = original.prototype;

  // return new constructor (will override original)
  return f;
}

@logClass
class Base {
    prop: number = 5;
}

class Extended extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}

var b = new Base()
console.log(b.prop)

var a = new Extended()
console.log(a.prop)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Throws this error: `TypeError: Class constructor Base cannot be invoked without 'new'`

Comment: @tmuecksch The code given by TSV and pablorsk work, but not in current (2018-05) jsFiddle, which gives the error you report. Paste our code in a .ts file, compile with tsc, run the generated js file with node, it should work.

Comment: It doesn't work in if the target is greater than es5!

Comment: ES6 will throw the `TypeError: Class constructor Base cannot be invoked without 'new'` error. Just replace `original.apply(this, args)` with `new original(args)` and it should work.

Comment: should be `new original(...args)`

Comment: Why do we need to make 'original' (reference to target) when we're not changing either? Because target gets overwritten by f? Without original, we could still use new target(...args) right? That reference doesn't change.

Comment: This is not 100% working.. `a.name` may return `Base` :( check @etech solution - it is better

Comment: @TSV What about non-legacy decorators? In this case, I don't get the `target` class as parameter but I get a `descriptor` object. How can we wrap the constructor in that case? Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

This is the more modern approach using the latest TS (3.2.4). The below also uses the decorator factory pattern so you can pass in attributes:

```js
function DecoratorName(attr: any) {
  return function _DecoratorName<T extends {new(...args: any[]): {}}>(constr: T){
    return class extends constr {
      constructor(...args: any[]) {
        super(...args)
        console.log('Did something after the original constructor!')
        console.log('Here is my attribute!', attr.attrName)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See here for more info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators

Comment: Tried this and it works fine unless you're in Angular :( In such a case the constructor `args` are assumed to be dependencies and so always `undefined` (even if some args are indeed provided) if this is not an `Injectable()` class

Comment: @Javarome Yep, if you're trying this on a class that already has a custom decorator like a Component in Angular, then there's a bunch of internal initialization logic that Angular is already doing, so you either have to try to replicate it all in your own custom decorator (not recommended at all, if even possible), or do a workaround like injecting your custom class or composing/constructing your class as a property/member of the Component class. There's not an easy workaround that I know of because of all the logic a framework like Angular has around its own decorators.

Comment: Would the order of decorators matter here?

Answer (score 13):

A solution using ES2015 Proxy to override the constructor:

```js
function wrap(target: any) {
  return new Proxy(target, {
    construct(clz, args) {
      console.log(`Constructing ${target.name}`);
      return Reflect.construct(clz, args);
    }
  });
}

@wrap
class Base {
  prop: number = 5;
}

class Extended extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}

var a = new Extended()
console.log(new Extended().prop);
```

You can also [run this on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ts-wrap-constructor?file=index.ts)

Comment: I'm curious about this approach. Shouldn't this be the accepted answer since this looks like a first party supported way of achieving the desired effect? Or are there pitfalls?

Comment: In most use cases, Proxy should be the better approach, especially as it helps keeping the type name of the created objects in the debugger. The only pitfall I can think of is that if you run `var b = new Base()` then `b.constructor == Base` will be false, since `b.constructor` would be the unproxied one. But not using Proxy would also encounter similar side-effect as one call `Object.getPrototypeOf(b)`; nothing is perfect.

Comment: Also, the `construct` method of the ProxyHandler object should accept a third parameter `newTarget: any` and pass it to `Reflect.construct`.

Comment: It works really nice - even `name` is properly set.. but Proxy can't be extended ;(

Answer (score 2):

The comments in the other answers complain that code doesn't work.
Actually, it works, but not in jsFiddle...
It is an issue with the code generation in jsFiddle (perhaps using an obsolete version of TypeScript).
The code above works with TypeScript 2.7.2 (run with Node).

So this is basically the code in pablorsk's answer (except there is no need to return the instance), I just added full types to please a stricter TSLint...

```
function logClass<T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(): any {
    type Ctor = new (...args: any[]) => T;
    return (target: T): Ctor => {
        // Save a reference to the original constructor
        const Original = target;

        // the new constructor behaviour
        let decoratedConstructor: any = function (...args: any[]): void {
            console.log("Before construction:", Original);
            Original.apply(this, args);
            console.log("After construction");
        };

        // Copy prototype so intanceof operator still works
        decoratedConstructor.prototype = Original.prototype;
        // Copy static members too
        Object.keys(Original).forEach((name: string) => { decoratedConstructor[name] = (<any>Original)[name]; });

        // Return new constructor (will override original)
        return decoratedConstructor;
    };
}

@logClass()
class Base {
    prop = 5;
    constructor(value: number) {
        console.log("Base constructor", value);
        this.prop *= value;
    }
    foo() { console.log("Foo", this.prop); }
    static s() { console.log("Static s"); }
}

class Extended extends Base {
    constructor(init: number) {
        super(init);
        console.log("Extended constructor", init);
    }
    bar() { console.log("Bar", this.prop); }
}

const b = new Base(2);
console.log("Base", b instanceof Base);
b.foo();
Base.s();

const e = new Extended(5);
console.log("Extended", e instanceof Base, e instanceof Extended);
e.bar();
```

[EDIT] Also added a line copying static members, otherwise decorated class throws an error when calling the static method.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Throws this exception: TypeError: Class constructor Bse cannot be invoked without 'new'.

Answer (score 0):

If you like [run code after and before constructor() with a decorator](https://gist.github.com/pablorsk/821bd55acefddd95e474652818e41462):

```
function ClassWrapper() {
    return function(target: any) {
        // save a reference to the original constructor
        var original = target;

        // the new constructor behaviour
        var f: any = function (...args) {
            console.log('ClassWrapper: before class constructor', original.name);
            let instance = original.apply(this, args)
            console.log('ClassWrapper: after class constructor', original.name);
            return instance;
        }

        // copy prototype so intanceof operator still works
        f.prototype = original.prototype;

        // return new constructor (will override original)
        return f;
    };
}
@ClassWrapper()
export class ClassExample {
    public constructor() {
        console.info('Running ClassExample constructor...');
    }
}

let example = new ClassExample();

/*
CONSOLE OUTPUT:
ClassWrapper: before class constructor ClassExample
Running ClassExample constructor...
ClassWrapper: after class constructor ClassExample
*/
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Throws this exception: `TypeError: Class constructor ClassExample cannot be invoked without 'new'`. The error is thrown in this line: `let instance = original.apply(this, args)`