# I cant really tell whats going on here

Tags: angular

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

function log(className) {
   console.log(className);
   return(...args) => {
     console.log("Arguments passed to this class constructor are ", args)
     return new className(...args)

   }
  }

@log 
  class myExample {
  constructor(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log("Constructor fired"); 
  }
}

const myClass = new myExample(5, 10)

@Component({ 
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'intro2angular';

  constructor() {
    console.log('This statement was generated by the constructor', this.aSimpleMethod(5, 2));   
  }

  aSimpleMethod(m, n) {
    // console.log("Hi Nicholas, I'm learning Angular!");
    return m*n
  }
}
```

It says error where i coded @log; it says Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression[image]. Someone should please help me resolve this because I'm truly a beginner in Angular

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `@log`?

Comment: I just want to take off the error from the @log, so that my code won't be throwing error again

Comment: What is @log, does this metatag even exist in Angular, at least you have to import it from somewhere.

Comment: Yes. Looks like you have either not defined the decorator, or haven’t imported it if it already exists. you can refer to this: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-decorators

Comment: Yeah the metatag does exist @IvanMihaylov

Comment: @lakaJS can you share what it does and where is it defined?

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava yeah but I don't get but thanks for the documentation, maybe it might be helpful here

Comment: You can remove the error by removing `@log`, I don't think you need it. I think you're confused, the `log(className)` function does not define the `@log` decorator.

Comment: You can get rid of the error if you cast the function returned in log to any. But your implementation of log isn't ideal for a decorator function as you [don't copy the prototype](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/features/typescript/class_decorators) and even if you do you might run into [problems with inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41220382/9423231). If you don't plan on adding this decorator to a class with an existing decorator then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526221/9423231) might be the best approach. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jxds1n

Comment: My thanks especially goes much to @AsthaSrivastava and fridoo. You guys are lovely first the awesome documentation, next the help rendered to me from fridoo. Thanks guys

Comment: But to be truthful, I resolved it long before the comments coming in the last 1-2 hours with the help of that documentation I get from @AsthaSrivastava.